# Windows Phone advanced binding

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, data-binding

I have some troubles getting things right with Windows Phone binding and a sequence of images. Let say I have an average rating between 1 - 10 and I have 5 images like a star rating system. Now I want to display the average rating with that images. Each star has value 2, so 5 stars filled is average rating of 10 and 1.5 star filled is average rating of 3. So some would be filled and some empty or half filled.

My XAML looks like:

```
 <Image HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="150,-20,0,0" Source="/Images/icon_star.png" Stretch="None"/>
 <Image HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="166,-20,0,0" Source="/Images/icon_star.png" Stretch="None"/>
 <Image HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="182,-20,0,0" Source="/Images/icon_star_half.png" Stretch="None"/>
 <Image HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="198,-20,0,0" Source="/Images/icon_star_empty.png" Stretch="None"/>
 <Image HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="214,-20,0,0" Source="/Images/icon_star_empty.png" Stretch="None"/>
```

This is my model:

```
 public class Comment
{
    public string comment { get; set; }
    public int c_id { get; set; }
    public double rating { get; set; }
    public string created { get; set; }
}
```

In Android it was easy with ratingbar widget or using list adapter for filling the images like this:

```
 Map<Integer, ImageView> vars = new HashMap<Integer, ImageView>();
    vars.put(1, view.star_1);
    vars.put(2, view.star_2);
    vars.put(3, view.star_3);
    vars.put(4, view.star_4);
    vars.put(5, view.star_5);

 while(i <= 5) {
        if(i <= rate) {
                ImageView star = vars.get(i);
                star.setImageDrawable(getContext().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_star));
        } else {
            if(rate % 2 != 0 && i == (int)(Math.round(rate))) {
                ImageView star = vars.get(i);
                star.setImageDrawable(getContext().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_star_half));
            } else {
                ImageView star = vars.get(i);
                star.setImageDrawable(getContext().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_star_dis));
            }
        }
        i++;
    }
```

In iOS I used images and IBOutletcollection and cellForRowAtIndexPath.

For Windows I used binding but I cannot get my head around this.

Comment: This http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/189242/XAML-Masking-for-WPF-Silverlight-and-WP-Rating-co

Comment: How can I limit these stars to return .5, 1, 1.5, 2, 2.5 etc only?

Comment: You may use ten different BitmapSources, where the first shows five empty stars, and the last shows five filled stars. Now you write a binding converter that converts a double value (between 1 and 10) to the appropriate BitmapImage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This operation is too complex for a simple binding.

What you will want to do is create a "Rating" user control. Then add a `Value` dependency property. That means you can do this:

```
<local:Rating Value="{Binding rating}"/>
```

The control itself would handle user input, constraining the values to multiples of .5, etc.